# How to write OP_CHECKMULTISIG for the following 1-of-2 multisig P2SH script

Tags: multi-signature

```
OP_IF
  OP_SHA256
  <hash of secret>
  OP_EQUALVERIFY
  <pubKey of swap>
  OP_CHECKSIG
OP_ELSE
  <relative locktime>
  OP_CHECKSEQUENCEVERIFY
  OP_DROP
  <pubKey of refund>
  OP_CHECKSIG
OP_ENDIF
```

Actual code which i am using for the above script is

```
const script = this.app.env.bitcoin.script.compile([
      hashOpcode,
      Buffer.from(secretHash, "hex"),
      this.app.env.bitcoin.opcodes.OP_EQUALVERIFY,
     Buffer.from(recipientPublicKey, "hex"),
      this.app.env.bitcoin.opcodes.OP_EQUAL,
      this.app.env.bitcoin.opcodes.OP_IF,                   
      Buffer.from(recipientPublicKey, "hex"),
      this.app.env.bitcoin.opcodes.OP_CHECKSIG,
     this.app.env.bitcoin.opcodes.OP_ELSE,
    this.app.env.bitcoin.script.number.encode(lockTime),
      this.app.env.bitcoin.opcodes.OP_CHECKSEQUENCEVERIFY,
      this.app.env.bitcoin.opcodes.OP_DROP,
      Buffer.from(ownerPublicKey, "hex"),
      this.app.env.bitcoin.opcodes.OP_CHECKSIG,
      this.app.env.bitcoin.opcodes.OP_ENDIF
    ]);
```

As we see that this script has just one  public key(**pubKey of swap**) to sign with. But i want to sign it with two public keys.
I searched for it but found nothing, can anybody guide me?

I just want to follow this pattern

```
 OP_0 [Sig 1] OP_1 [PK 1][PK 2] OP_2 OP_CHECKMULTISIG
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand from your question (correct me if I'm wrong), you want to have a script that in the `OP_IF` part pays to 1-of-2 public keys. You could try the below script:

```
OP_IF
  OP_SHA256
  OP_DATA (0x20)
  <hash of secret>
  OP_EQUALVERIFY
  OP_1 
  OP_DATA (0x21) 
  <pubKey of swap1>
  OP_DATA (0x21)
  <pubkey of swap2>
  OP_2
  OP_CHECKMULTISIG
OP_ELSE
  OP_DATA (size of relative_locktime)
  <relative locktime>
  OP_CHECKSEQUENCEVERIFY
  OP_DROP
  OP_DATA (0x21)
  <pubKey of refund>
  OP_CHECKSIG
OP_ENDIF
```

You could spend this script with: `<0> <sig1> <secret> 1`

Comment: Yes @Ugam Kamat you are actually right.
I have edit my question please see it again..Actually the complication which i am facing is, how to provide these two public keys . Is it the right way?    ```                  var add=[recipientPublicKey,exchangePublicKey]                  Whereas Inside compile Buffer.from(add, "hex"),
this.app.env.bitcoin.opcodes.OP_2,
this.app.env.bitcoin.opcodes.CHECKMULTISIG,                                                                          Is it correct?

Comment: @Aqeel You need to use a `OP_DATA` opcode between them to indicate the bytes of data to push to stack. For example, to push hash_of_secret to stack you need to tell the program to push the next 32 bytes which is the reason we need `0x20` preceding that as shown in my edited answer

Comment: Thanks for reply. But Opcode you listed "OP_DATA" is not a valid opcode. I have printed the list of opcodes but that opcode is not in the list and therefor creating error

Comment: @Aqeel It's not exactly an opcode but a parameter that helps you indicate to the software how much data you want to push on the stack. For example, if you see my script i used `0x20` before hash of secret. It indicates to the software to push the next 32 bytes (ox20 in hex) on the stack. Before the pubkey I used 0x21 to indicate pushing the next 33 bytes on the stack (assuming you are using compressed pub keys)

Comment: Can you provide me any helping material for 1-of-2 p2sh multisig script, which may helps me in writing script in desired format.

Comment: @Aqeel I don't think there is one specific to 1-of-2 p2sh multisig. Even if it is out there I'm oblivious to it

Comment: actually the thing which i want to see is how can i pass list of pubkeys to apply OP_CHECKMULTISIG in desired code format...
The ref repo is: https://github.com/swaponline/swap.core/blob/97d1d5b6afffee97869302443924bef79ce42763/src/swap.swaps/BtcSwap.js#L181
I am changing this piece of script to 1-of-2 p2sh multisig. 
Any guidance for me after seeing this script form above reference link?

Comment: @Aqeel I haven't gone through the code in detail, but maybe you can repeat `Buffer.from(recipientPublicKey, 'hex'),` twice with different public key and then instead of `this.app.env.bitcoin.opcodes.OP_CHECKSIG` use `this.app.env.bitcoin.opcodes.OP_CHECKMULTISIG`